# Using EF/LINQ to copy a record from one table to another (archiving a record)

Tags: linq, entity-framework

Not in SQL but in C# using Entity Framework:  Is there a simple way to copy a source record to another table?  The column definitions are identical however the target table has no indices, keys or constraints.  I have this code and the one line I am having trouble with is marked:

```
private void HandleAutos()
{
    // convert to List<auto>...
    List<Model.Auto> imports = ConvertAuto();

    // get all DB records in List<auto>...
    List<Model.Auto> current = _dbFeed.Autoes.Where(a => a.ClientID == _targetClientID && a.Active == true).ToList();

    // isolate all Inserts, Updates and Deletes...
    var existing = imports.Intersect(current, new AutoIsIn()).ToList();         // should be all autos with matching VIN & SKU  //
    var updates = existing.Intersect(current, new AutoHasChanged()).ToList();   // should be a subset of changed resords        //
    var inserts = imports.Except(current, new AutoIsIn()).ToList();             // should be all the imports not in the DB      //
    var deletes = current.Except(imports, new AutoIsIn()).ToList();             // should be all the DB records not in imports  //

    // THIS IS THE BAD LINE //
    deletes.ForEach(a => _dbFeed.AddToAutoArchives(a));  // <=======
    // -------------------- //
    deletes.ForEach(a => _dbFeed.DeleteObject(a));
    updates.ForEach(a => _dbFeed.ApplyCurrentValues("Autoes", a));
    inserts.ForEach(a => _dbFeed.AddToAutoes(a));

    _dbFeed.SaveChanges();
}
```

I know I can loop through my source records, create an Archive record, copy each property over and finally add the new entity to the ArchiveAutos collection and save it to the DB.  Before I went down that path and wrote a method to copy a record from an Auto entity to an AutoArchive entity I though I would check to see if there is already some awesome sweetness already baked in.

Do you know if there is any?

TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution I came up with:

```
// Archive the records to be deleted...
if (_deletes.Count > 0)
{
    // ignore deletes less than 60 days old...
    var myDeletes = _deletes.Where(a => a.DateCreated <= DateTime.Now.AddDays(-60)).ToList();

    List<Model.AutoArchive> archiveList = ConvertAuto(myDeletes);
    archiveList.ForEach(a => _dbFeed.AutoArchives.Add(a));
    _dbFeed.SaveChanges();

    // Drop the records no longer in the feed...
    foreach (var d in myDeletes)
    {
        var myImages = _dbFeed.Images.Where(a => a.ParentRecordID == d.AutoID).ToList();
        myImages.ForEach(a => _dbFeed.Images.Remove(a));
    }
    myDeletes.ForEach(a => _dbFeed.Autoes.Remove(a));
    _dbFeed.SaveChanges();
}

private List<Model.AutoArchive> ConvertAuto(List<Model.Auto> deletes)
{
    List<Model.AutoArchive> aa = new List<Model.AutoArchive>();
    foreach (var a in deletes)
    {
        aa.Add(new Model.AutoArchive
        {
            ID = Guid.NewGuid(),
            Active = a.Active,
            ....
            ImageList = a.ImageList
        });
    }

    return aa;
}
```

Ugly as hell but it works.  :(

Answer (score 0):

you might want to consider using a stored procedure to accomplish the archiving of the record and just call that from within your C# code, that is much cleaner and easier way, also it allows you to avoid the round trip for all the data

Comment: This is very true and I would in a production environment.  However, I am trying to learn all I can about LINQ and especially Lambdas.  :)

Comment: great place to start, 101 LINQ Samples, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/aa336746

Comment: Also, please note that the first record set is **not** from the DB.  It is in fact from a CSV file...